# why nestjs typeorm restart database auto change to default value

Tags: nestjs, node.js-typeorm

script.entity.ts

```
  @ManyToOne((type) => ProjectEntity, (project) => project.scriptVoList)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: "projectId", //restart server then this field auto change to  null,why?
  })
  @ApiProperty({ type: () => ProjectEntity })
  projectVo: ProjectEntity;
```

project.entity.ts

```
  @OneToMany((type) => ScriptEntity, (script) => script.projectVo)
  @ApiProperty()
  scriptVoList: ScriptEntity[];
```

restart server then  projectId field auto change to  null,why?

Comment: are you using `synchronize: true` right?

Comment: I do it with false, now Solved，thank you